# XSLT: Read encoding information in xml-input-file

Tags: xml, encoding, utf-8, version, declaration

Is there any chance to gain the encoding information from the XML declaration, in the XSLT context?

Furthermore I'm interested in finding out if my input file has an encoding information or not (or has a xml-declaration or not if input is plain text):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
...

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
...
```

Answer (score 1):

No, this information isn't part of the data model. It's not really useful to know how the original document was encoded because by the time you see it in XPath or XSLT the decoding has already been done (or has failed, if the encoding declaration was wrong). In fact, the document you see in XPath or XSLT might not even have started life as lexical XML at all, e.g. in a pipeline it could be the output of another transformation or a database query.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. Is there any other solution to get the xml declaration for example as a string from (maybe) an _external file_ in context of xslt or xproc? Is it possible to treat the source file as plain text and check if the first string starts with <?xml... ?> by using the document() function?

Comment: What do you want to do with the information? Do you care if the document has multiple external entities whose encoding might differ? Note that DOM gives you getInputEncoding() and getXmlEncoding() - I've never used either.